# batch cd to path contains dots

Tags: batch-file, copy

I'm writing a script to copy files from folder to another . the problem is that my path contains .com in it for exmple:

```
c:\program files\sos.com\ydb_jobs\...
```

now when I put that under    copy /v I get syntax error 
my script is :

```
call c:\configdir\configdironfigfile.bat
cd %directory% 
copy /v path\a.txt path\b.txt
```

- path is an extension to the directory
- and     %directory% is imported from my config file
- and it's the path with .com

can anyone know how can I pass this issue ?

Comment: I would guess that you need to put your paths in quotes: `copy /v "path\a.txt" "path\b.txt"`

Comment: I tried that but it's still giving me syntax errors pointing to the     .com and mark it blue

Comment: What OS are you using?  And is this cmd or powershell?

Comment: Windows  and yes it's cmd not powershell .

Comment: "pointing to the .com and mark it blue" -- this does not sound like cmd behavior.  Can you screenshot your output?

Comment: it does that in notepad when I open the script.  but in cmd it gives me command syntax error

Comment: Are you using `notepad.exe` or another text editor? Notepad has no syntax highlighting, even for url's...

Comment: no I'm using bat script as I described in the question  . notepad++ is just a tool where I can edit my script. it can be the space between the program files buy that I know quote will fix so it's the only thing I can think of